# Ad is not rendering

Tags: javascript, google-publisher-tag

I'm trying to launch some ads using Ad Manager. when I generate the ad tag and run it on a test page, it doesn't work. I've taken the ad tags directly from Ad Manager and implemented them, as is, for testing purposes.

**Here's the example implementation with some mock test ads;**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        var REFRESH_KEY = 'refresh';
        var REFRESH_VALUE = 'false';
googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXXXXXX/desktop_footer_728x90', [[970, 90], [728, 90], [1, 1]], 'div-gpt-ad-1588045067863-0').setTargeting(REFRESH_KEY, REFRESH_VALUE).addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>    

<div id='div-gpt-ad-1588045067863-0'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1588045067863-0'); });
  </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When this renders, it results in the following;

```
<div id="gpt_unit_/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXX_XXXXXX_NAME" data-google-query-id="CLDR5_WWmOkCFUmVaAodifwBzg">
    <div id="google_ads_iframe_/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXX_XXXXXX_NAME_1__container__" style="border: 0pt none; width: 468px; height: 60px;"></div>
</div>

<iframe id="google_osd_static_frame_7289463933878" name="google_osd_static_frame" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to turn off ad blocker extension

Comment: Yes...I don't have any kind of ad blocker extn.

Comment: Try to use VPN sometimes it works. I was facing the same issue because the ads account was set regionally.

Comment: @FirmanPutra You are right, But for this ad i have not specify any region.

Answer (score 1):

Your integration seems good, but no ad is set up in Google Ad Manager GUI so nothing is shown up.

**How to know if your ad integration is good :**

- if there is a data-google-query-id it means the ad call happened.
- if the generated iframe is in display:none, it means nothing is called,
  so the adcall remains empty.
- you can use the Google Publisher Console (see [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2462712?hl=en)) to make
  sure all is properly set up and to get details about the calls.

I think you need to launch a campaign targeting your inventory to get the ad to show up.

Hope this helps.